# Error: BehaviorSubject in Angular 2

Tags: angular

[image]

---

```
receiveMessage(){
 this.messaging.onMessage(function (payload) {
    console.log("Message received. ", payload);
      this.currentMessage.next(payload)
  });
}
```

---

**TypeError: Cannot read property 'next' of undefined**

Comment: can you show how currentMessage is declared or defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using an arrow function as follows,

```
 this.messaging.onMessage((payload) => {
      console.log('Message received. ', payload);
      this.currentMessage.next(payload);
 });
```

and make sure you have imported,

```
import {BehaviorSubject} from 'rxjs/BehaviorSubject';
```

Comment: Thank u very much .i was trying last two days

Answer (score 0):

> Important To Know

Until arrow functions, every new function defined its own this value (a new object in the case of a constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the base object if the function is called as an "object method", etc.). This proved to be less than ideal with an object-oriented style of programming.
read more [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions)